# C++ program has stopped working

Tags: c++, pointers, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I am making a quite simple program, just a little chat bot AI kind of thing, and I have some code, c++ of course, for the program. I don't get any errors but when I run it a window comes up saying program.exe has stopped working, like it stopped responding. My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>
#include<conio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct strarray{
   char* array[];
};

struct keyword{
   string keywords;
   string responses[];       
};


keyword * dictionary = new keyword[2];
keyword defaultr;

keyword getMatch(string key);
string sconvert(string con);
void init();
string getResp(keyword key);

bool cont=true;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   string input;
   while(cont){
            getline(cin,input);
            cout << getResp(getMatch(input));
            getch();
            getch();
   }
}

string sconvert(string con){
   con.erase(remove_if(con.begin(), con.end(), ::isspace), con.end());
   con.erase(remove_if(con.begin(), con.end(), ::ispunct), con.end());
   return con;
}

void init(){
   srand(time(NULL));
   dictionary[0].keywords="hello";
   dictionary[0].responses[0]="Hello, how have you been?";
   dictionary[0].responses[1]="Hello, have you missed me?";
   dictionary[0].responses[2]="Hey, how's it going?";
   defaultr.responses[0]="That's interesting, tell me more.";
   defaultr.responses[1]="Please, tell me more.";
}

keyword getMatch(string key){
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(dictionary); i++){
            if(key==dictionary[i].keywords){return dictionary[i];}
    }
    return defaultr;
}

string getResp(keyword key){
   return key.responses[rand() % sizeof(key)];
}
```

When I run it, it opens up normally, but after I input something when it comes up it "stops working". Could somebody please tell me what I need to change, and why would be appreciated.

Is there some pointer problem? Or something with the `rand`? I'm really confused and would appreciate some advice on how to better this program so it actually works.

Comment: For one, you never call your init() method so the dictionary never gets initialized.

Comment: It sounds like you're not running through the debugger. You should run through the debugger because it will break on the exception and you can find out exactly why it's crashing.

Comment: What an fascinating mix of advanced STL and complete ignorance of the STL.  I'm intruiged.  Look up how to use a `std::map` and `std::vector`, which would make this code a lot easier and less error prone.

Comment: I added the init method to the main, and I am running windows Vista, still getting the same problem. And I don't just need sarcastic criticism, thank you very much, I would just appreciate some help as to how to fix this. Saying I am ignorant of STL but not saying what I did wrong or anything about STL is just as stupid.

Comment: Okay, I tried debugging, there is an access violation(segmentation fault), I'm using dev++

Comment: It would appear as though the fault is happening as soon as it goes to getMatch, as I added a few debug cout's.

Comment: i suggest you to download Visual C++, it's debugger is much better

Comment: In the definition of the keyword struct, you are defining responses to be a zero-length array of strings. Surely this is not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(dictionary)` will give `sizeof(keyword*)`, probably `4` or `8`, so you will iterate over the end of the dictionary array and terminate.

Easiest fix: Define a constant to store the array length.

```
const dictionarySize = 2;
```

and use that throughout.

You also need to change `struct keyword` to:

```
struct keyword{
   string keywords;
   string responses[3];       
};
```

Comment: Thank you, you actually provided some help, unlike the rest of these guys just criticizing me without giving me anything useful.

Comment: Better yet, use a std::vector or other container that knows its size, rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

first of all u have an infinite loop so the program should work for ever .. I took a glance at the code and using rand() % sizeof(key) is wrong, the responses is not predetermined so either you set it to a specific value for example

```
struct keyword {
    string keywords;
    string responses[2];       
};
rand() % sizeof(key.responses)
```

or you make your structure like this

```
struct keyword {
    string keywords;
    vector<string> responses;      
};
rand() % key.responses.size()
//After setting the responses by push_back for example
```

there are other ways but this is safer and no memory management needed ...

Comment: I changed that to sizeof(key.responses), and realize the infinite loop, i intentionally did that, i'll change that later. I added the definition for the size of responses array, and I still get the segmentation fault. BTW, I edited a few things, it is definitely during the getmatch function, wtf is wrong here, someone just tell me.

Comment: write your new code .. one more thing it is better to initialize all keywords